# How optimal get one Entry (Record) by id with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, record, jooq

I think that is very simple, but I cannot find anything simple in the docs.

How optimal get one Entry (Record) by id with JOOQ?

Something like for creation of Record:

```
factory.newRecord(MY_TABLE);
```

also

```
MyTableRecord record = factory.selectRecord(MY_TABLE.ID.like(id));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apart from what [yellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15158509/521799) suggested in his answer, you can also use this "short form" here:

```
MyTableRecord record = factory.fetchOne(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.ID.like(id));
```

With jOOQ 2.x's [`Factory.fetchOne(Table, Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/2.6.x/org/jooq/impl/Factory.html#fetchOne%28org.jooq.Table,%20org.jooq.Condition%29) or jOOQ 3.x's [`DSLContext.fetchOne(Table, Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchOne%28org.jooq.Table,%20org.jooq.Condition%29) method.

Answer (score 5):

I use `selectFrom` and `fetchOne`

```
    PersonRecord record = factory.selectFrom(PERSON).
                                  where(PERSON.UUID.equal(uuid)).fetchOne();
```